# How do I make a number to equal another number in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

is there a way to get a paramater to be equal a different number?
for example - user entered the number "2" when asked to choose a number.
I want the bot to return the answer "your 2 is equal to 120"
and so on.
so the text will be "your $number is equal to $indexnumber"
I know that there isnt a way to calculate in dialogflow, but maybe an index can bypass that somehow.
 that I can make a list where a number == another number depends on the user input.

thanks!
Dex.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to setup fulfillment to process parameter values.  See this tutorial for how to setup fulfillment: https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation#enable_webhook_in_dialogflow